# Setting body to margin:0 causes CSS animation issue in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I've been working on variations of this issue for a while. Currently I have the animation working in all browsers, but setting the body margin to 0 in FF breaks it as shown below.

I've had to target all other browsers, set the body margin, and just leave it showing in FF. Obviously this isn't ideal as I'd like the layout to be uniform.

***Please use firefox to re-create the issue.***

Here's the working [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L8ux4f84/)

HTML

```
<header class="header">
<div class="header-container">
<div class="top-header-ani ani slide-t navbar">
<a href="index2.html">Home</a></div>

<div class="main-header-ani"><span class="mainheader">△</span></div>

<div class="bottom-header-ani ani slide-b">
<span class="maintitle">tetris<span class="yel">for</span>kicks</span>
<br>
<span class="subtitle">web development &amp; design</span></div>
</div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
       margin-top: 50px;
   }



   .header-container {
       width: 100%;
       height: 200px;
       margin: 100px 0 0 0;
       position: absolute;
   }

   .main-header-ani {
       font-family: 'quicksand', helvetica;
       text-align: center;
       line-height: 200px;
       background-color: #a2aba2;
       width: 100%;
       height: 200px;
       position: relative;
   }

   .top-header-ani {
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       text-align: center;
       position: relative;
       z-index: -1;
   }

   .bottom-header-ani {
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       text-align: center;
       position: relative;
       z-index: -1;
   }
   /*................... index font stying ...................*/

   .yel {
       color: #eac961;
   }

   .navbar {
       text-transform: uppercase;
       font-family: helvetica;
       word-spacing: 10px;
   }

   .maintitle {
       color: #a2aba2;
       font-family: helvetica;
       font-size: 50pt;
   }

   .mainheader {
       color: #fff;
       font-size: 110pt;
   }

   .subtitle {
       font-family: helvetica;
   }

   header a {
       color: #000;
       text-decoration: none;
   }

   header a:hover,
   header a.hover {
       color: #eac961;
   }
   /*................... index header animations ...................*/

   .ani {
       -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
       animation-duration: 2s;
       -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
       animation-fill-mode: both;
   }

   .slide-t {
       animation-name: slide-t;
   }

   @keyframes slide-t {
       from {
           transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
           visibility: visible;
       }
       to {
           transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
       }
   }

   .slide-b {
       animation-name: slide-b;
   }

   @keyframes slide-b {
       from {
           transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
           visibility: visible;
       }
       to {
           transform: translate3d(0, 10%, 0);
       }
   }
```

Run the above. You'll see that both animations transtion from behind the heasder div perfectly.

If you add the CSS:

```
body {
margin: 0
}
```

To the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/us9xrzun/2/), you'll notice the bottom aniation stretches as it plays out.

*Does anyone know why this is occuring?
Does anyone know how to fix it?*

I've tried -moz- animations settings, no effect.

**I've also got an idea for a work around:**

Currently in firefox I get a scroll bar at the bottom due to the extra space taken up by the body's margin. If there's a way for me to set the scroll position to the absolute right by default, I can hide the X scroll bar and disable it which would hide the body margin entierly.

-

Anyway, this one's killing me. Any ideas are greatly appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've figured out the issue.

It's actually a display driver issue with my laptop. XPS 13 9530.

My friend checked the test site upload on his PC and it works perfectly as it is, I get the ghosting on my laptop. So I tested on another PC, and it works perfectly.

I disabled hardware acceleration in my FF and it works perfectly.

I've tried various graphics drivers, but it appears to be a windows 10 issue with my laptop. I'm getting a few other weird issues with firefox rendering, for instance the close buttons on my tab bars are duplicated, sometimes FF loads with a full white screen and I need to restart it, etc...

So, mark this as fixed. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: You can [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi), including the graphics info from about:support. You can also try disabling only D2D (gfx.direct2d.disabled=true) or switching to D3D9 (layers.prefer-d3d9=true) in about:config, instead of disabling HWA completely.

Comment: I can't check my own answer for 2 days.

I will Oriol, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "px" values for firefox, not "%" for

```
transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
```

Comment: Works in the Jsfiddle, but not for my site.

I've uploaded a test version of my site, is there anything you can see that might be causing it? It works fine until I edit the body margin value...

Open in Firefox: http://test2.tetrisforkicks.com/

Answer (score 0):

Import the normalize.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css">
```

or download it from:
[Here](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.3/normalize.css)

Comment: I've set the link on the relevant pages, made sure  no styles come before it as instructed, and the issue persists.

Is there something else I need to do to get it working?

Comment: Additionally try to Import the reset.css
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

I have tried a reset.css on your JSFiddle and it's work try it and let me know if you need any help more.

Comment: Can you post a working Jsfiddle with the reset.css please?

I've tried linking it to a file on my system and usinga cdn and neither works.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gpvzq47z/

Take the reset and normalize links to your html in js it is on css

Comment: It works in the jsfiddle, but not on the main site.

Here's the code I'm testing it on: http://test2.tetrisforkicks.com/

Comment: Strange, cause on my Firefox it works perfectly what is your browser version ?

Comment: Latest. 

Have you tried applying it to the test site I linked? If it does work, could you supply  the html file you've used just in case I'm doing overlooking something obvious?

Really appreicate your help.

Comment: How can I apply the code to your website which is hosted :)
I think you shouldn't obsess about it cause I said it looks perfect on my PC
Hint: reset.css and normalize.css for fix the disordinance between browsers search about it.

Comment: You could view the source code, copy it, and create your own version.

Also I'm not obsessing about the cause, I simply prefer to know why instead of sticking a band-aid over the problem,

Also the issue's been solved. ;)

Comment: I think you already share your code in JSFiddle ;) I am glad if it's solved, if my answer helped you, wish you mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Yes, but the point was it was working in Jsfiddle but not on my main site. IE: there could have been a conflict with the extra code the existed on the main site.

And thank you for your help, but your answer wasn't the key as the issue was something else entirely.